# Accessing a attribute after my graph visitor is finished

Tags: c++, boost, destructor, boost-graph

I have a problem using the breadth first search from the boost graph library.
I want to get an attribute of my visitor class after the visit of my graph is finished.

```
// init my visitor
BfsVisitor bv;
// auto like in C++-0x
BOOST_AUTO (visit, boost::visitor(bv));
// launch search
boost::breadth_first_search (graph, vertex, visit);
// get result ("typedef pair<string, int*> result")
result res = bv.getResult();
// print res: SegFault, `res.second' is NULL
std::cout << *(res.second) << std::endl;
```

My BfsVisitor is defined like so:

```
class BfsVisitor : public boost::default_bfs_visitor
{
public:
  BfsVisitor()
  {
    std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()
          <<" ~~ CONSTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }
  BfsVisitor(const BfsVisitor& b)
    : boost::bfs_visitor<>(),
      _res (b._res),
      _arg (b._arg)
  {
    std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()
              <<" ~~ COPY" << std::endl;
  }
  ~BfsVisitor()
  {
    std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()
              <<" ~~ DESTRUCTOR" << std::endl;
  }

  /// Visitor methods
  void discover_vertex(const vertex_t& s,
                       const Graph& g)
  {
    std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()
              << " -> Discover vertex: " << g[s]._id << std::endl;
    Executive exec* = g[s]._executive;
    _arg.insert(_res);
    exec->setArguments(_arg);
    // other process
  }
  void examine_vertex(const vertex_t& s,
                      const Graph& g)
  {
    std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()
              << " -> Examine vertex: " << g[s]._id << std::endl;
    Executive exec* = g[s]._executive;
    exec->launch(&_res);
    // other process
  }

  /// Getter
  result getResult() const
  {
    std::cout << boost::this_thread::get_id()
              << " ~~ Get Result" << std::endl;
    return _res;
  }

private:
  result _res;
  argument _arg; // typedef std::map
}
```

I guess my problem come of the combo copy/destruction of my visitor during the process: here an output example on a little graph ( [1] -> [2] -> [3] ) using only one thread

```
b7495b40 ~~ COPY
b7495b40 ~~ COPY
b7495b40 ~~ DESTRUCTOR
b7495b40 ~~ COPY
b7495b40 ~~ COPY
b7495b40 ~~ COPY
b7495b40 ~~ COPY
b7495b40 -> Discover vertex: 1
b7495b40 -> Examine vertex: 1
b7495b40 -> Discover vertex: 2
b7495b40 -> Examine vertex: 2
b7495b40 -> Discover vertex: 3
b7495b40 -> Examine vertex: 3
b7495b40 ~~ DESTRUCTOR
b7495b40 ~~ DESTRUCTOR
b7495b40 ~~ DESTRUCTOR
b7495b40 ~~ DESTRUCTOR
b7495b40 ~~ Get Result
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I just want to access to my attribute at the end of all the process I do in the examine_vertex method. I checked the boost graph visitor documentation but I did not find anything about a solution for my problem.
Hoping you'll have an idea to suggest.

Comment: Please provide a short self contained compiling example.  Pseudo code is or limited usefulness.  The code above takes no `Args`, and has no `_res`, and has a bad copy constructor, and is obviously not a minimal example of your problem.  Make a complete short example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Yakk I fixed my code to add the attribute and some process but my process work as I want. I can print the individual result without any problems. I can't give you the Executive class so you have to trust the problem is not in it. For the copy constructor, I used it only to print the call. I don't define it myself normally.

Comment: From [here](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/doc/breadth_first_search.html#1): "Since the visitor parameter is passed by value, if your visitor contains state then any changes to the state during the algorithm will be made to a copy of the visitor object, not the visitor object passed in. Therefore you may want the visitor to hold this state by pointer or reference.".

Comment: Thank you, I did not see the note... Seems to work now.

Comment: An yes -- where `_res` comes from was rather important.  :) @llonesmiz you should post the answer, so Turgal can accept it